# Can't add Online accounts in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am going to settings -> online accounts and the pressing add account button and getting nothing it will not respond. This is on an ubuntu 16.04 machine it's not throwing any errors it just does nothing. My question is what do I do next to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem trying to use the flickr plugin for Shotwell. Googling around I had no useful answer to this.

If I launch the account manager from terminal with `sudo online-accounts-preferences` I have indeed no errors.

Solution in my case: launch the synaptic package manager, search for "flickr", you will see an item "account-plugin-flickr", install that one and restart the application or the PC.

Depending what online account your are trying to install, a similar procedure should fix your problem.